# LIBGDX: Calling a rectangle from another class resulting in NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, libgdx

PlayScreen Class:

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {

private Player player;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
private TiledMap map;
private Rectangle rightRectangle, leftRectangle, playerRectangle;


@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.render();

    renderer.getSpriteBatch().begin();
    player.draw(renderer.getSpriteBatch());
    renderer.getSpriteBatch().end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    camera.viewportWidth = width;
    camera.viewportHeight = height;
    camera.update();

}

@Override
public void show() {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    map = new TiledMap();
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);

    player = new Player(new Sprite(new Texture("img/player.png")), playerRectangle);
    playerRectangle = player.rectangle;
    rightRectangle = new Rectangle(1280,0,0,720);
    leftRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,0,720);


    boolean wallLeft = leftRectangle.overlaps(player.rectangle);
    boolean wallRight = rightRectangle.overlaps(player.rectangle);


    if(wallLeft){
        System.out.println("wallLeft Overlap");
        player.velocity.x = 0;
    }
    else if(wallRight){
        System.out.println("wallRight Overlap");
        player.velocity.x = 0;

    }

    player.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2f - player.getWidth()/2f,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2f - player.getHeight()/2f - Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5f);

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    dispose();
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    map.dispose();
    player.getTexture().dispose();
    renderer.dispose();

}

}
```

Player Class:

```
public class Player extends Sprite{

public Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();
private float speed = 500;
public Rectangle rectangle;


public Player(Sprite sprite, Rectangle rectangle){
    super(sprite);
    this.rectangle = rectangle;

}

public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch){

    update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    super.draw(spriteBatch);
}

public void update(float delta) {

    rectangle = new Rectangle(getX() + velocity.x * delta,0,286,160);

    setX(getX() + velocity.x * delta);

}

}
```

So, I'm using Rectangles to detect my collisions. I have set rightRectangle and leftRectangle as my screen's side bounds. I want to assign the player a sprite and a rectangle. I'm dealing with the collision in the PlayScreen class but it's resulting in a NullPointerException. Need help figuring why I'm getting NullPointerException.

Thanks !

NullPointerException:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle.overlaps(Rectangle.java:210)
    at net.dermetfan.asteroids.screens.PlayScreen.show(PlayScreen.java:62)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:62)
    at net.dermetfan.asteroids.screens.MainMenu$1.clicked(MainMenu.java:75)
    at  
        com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener.touchUp(ClickListener.java:82)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener.handle(InputListener.java:57)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.touchUp(Stage.java:329)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglInput.processEvents(LwjglInput.java:297)
    at 
     com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:209)
    at    
       com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace so we can see the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe problem is with your playerRectangle.

```
player = new Player(new Sprite(new Texture("img/player.png")), playerRectangle); // playerRectangle not initialized!
playerRectangle = player.rectangle;
rightRectangle = new Rectangle(1280,0,0,720);
leftRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,0,720);
```

Try something like this

```
    playerRectangle=new Rectangle(x,y,w,h);
 player = new Player(new Sprite(new Texture("img/player.png")), playerRectangle); 
    playerRectangle = player.rectangle; // i don't even think you should put this line is useless
     rightRectangle = new Rectangle(1280,0,0,720);
        leftRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,0,720);
```

Now you shouldn't have any errors.

Or better do this in your player class, you don't need a playerRectangle in your main class

```
    public Player(Sprite sprite){
    super(sprite);
    this.rectangle = sprite.getBoundingRectangle();

}
```

And in your class

```
   player = new Player(new Sprite(new Texture("img/player.png")));        
         rightRectangle = new Rectangle(1280,0,0,720);
            leftRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,0,720);
```

Comment: sorry, should I add this line:
   playerRectangle=new Rectangle(x,y,w,h);
and make x,y,w and h be floats ? I tried not adding this line and removing the playerRectangle = player.rectangle; line and still ran into an error.

Comment: You need to initialize it. Check my edit, because you really don't need the player rectangle in your main class

Comment: Thanks! I went with your edit and removed the playerRectangle in my main class. Originally I never had it and have been fiddling around with it and decided to just leave playerRectangle in my main class. But anyways, after taking it out, it runs fine(?), but there's no collision happening. The leftRectangle and rightRectangle are never overlapping with the player for some reason. Do you know why it's not overlapping?

Comment: Try to render your rectangles and see what is the problem :) Don't forget to accept my answer!